# Optimizer problem with tensorflows distribution strategy and tf.keras models

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras

When using the distributed strategy MirroredStrategy, we experience a
poor validation accuracy.
Running the training without the distribution strategy on a single GPU,
the training and validation accuracy are above 95%.

The problem arises with the tf.keras.resnet50 model. With "self-built" small
CNNs, the distribution strategy works fine.

It seems like the optimizer has problems with tf.keras models.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem and how to solve it?
We ran out of ideas.

### General setup

- CUDA 10.0
- tf-nightly-gpu 2.1.0.dev20191029
- 2x RTX 2080 Ti
- custom grayscale images (270, 270) with a well tested input pipeline based on tf.data.Dataset. Small CNNs are performing above 95% accuracy.

### What we already tried and led to similar behaviour:

- self-built tf2.0 with CUDA10.1
- pip package tensorflow-gpu (V2.0.0) with CUDA 10.0
- different optimizers

#### Setup A:

ResNet50 on a single gpu performing above 95% validation accuray.

#### Setup B:

ResNet50 in the MirroredStrategy scope with 2 GPUs performing less than 70%
validation accuracy.

Batch sizes are a multiple of two since we use two GPUs.

#### Code:

```py
df_trainset[target_label] = df_trainset[target_label].astype('int')
df_validset[target_label] = df_validset[target_label].astype('int')
df_testset[target_label] = df_testset[target_label].astype('int')

list_labels_train = df_trainset[target_label]
list_paths_train = df_trainset['sample_path']

list_labels_valid = df_validset[target_label]
list_paths_valid = df_validset['sample_path']

list_labels_test = df_testset[target_label]
list_paths_test = df_testset['sample_path']

def parse_img(label, path):
    img = tf.io.read_file(path)
    img = tf.image.decode_png(img, channels=1, dtype=tf.uint8)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    return img, label

BATCH_SIZE = 32

ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((list_labels_train,
                                               list_paths_train))

ds_train = ds_train.map(parse_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
ds_train = ds_train.cache()
ds_train = ds_train.shuffle(buffer_size=len(list_paths_train), seed=42,
                            reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
ds_train = ds_train.batch(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True).repeat()
ds_train = ds_train.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

train_steps = np.ceil(len(list_paths_train) / BATCH_SIZE)

# valid
ds_valid = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((list_labels_valid,
                                               list_paths_valid))
ds_valid = ds_valid.map(parse_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
ds_valid = ds_valid.cache()
ds_valid = ds_valid.shuffle(buffer_size=len(list_paths_valid), seed=42,
                            reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
ds_valid = ds_valid.batch(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True).repeat()
ds_valid = ds_valid.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

valid_steps = np.ceil(len(list_paths_valid) / BATCH_SIZE)


strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = ResNet50(include_top=True,
                     weights=None,
                     input_tensor=None,
                     input_shape=(270, 270, 1),
                     pooling=None,
                     classes=3)

    model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=["accuracy"],
                  )

model.summary()


history = model.fit(
        x=ds_train,
        epochs=10,
        verbose=1,
        validation_data=ds_valid,
        steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
        validation_steps=valid_steps,
        use_multiprocessing=False)
```

#### Results

Training on one device, without distribution strategy, everything looks fine.

[Full console-dump on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/GupeVFmj)

```
563/563 [==============================] - 141s 250ms/step - loss: 0.1185 - accuracy: 0.9616 - val_loss: 0.5751 - val_accuracy: 0.8078
Epoch 2/10
563/563 [==============================] - 130s 231ms/step - loss: 0.0400 - accuracy: 0.9865 - val_loss: 0.8953 - val_accuracy: 0.7119
Epoch 3/10
563/563 [==============================] - 130s 231ms/step - loss: 0.0478 - accuracy: 0.9870 - val_loss: 25.3537 - val_accuracy: 0.3367
Epoch 4/10
563/563 [==============================] - 130s 230ms/step - loss: 0.0309 - accuracy: 0.9906 - val_loss: 0.0576 - val_accuracy: 0.9946
Epoch 5/10
563/563 [==============================] - 129s 230ms/step - loss: 0.0210 - accuracy: 0.9940 - val_loss: 0.0780 - val_accuracy: 0.9916
Epoch 6/10
563/563 [==============================] - 130s 230ms/step - loss: 0.0227 - accuracy: 0.9937 - val_loss: 0.0595 - val_accuracy: 0.9887
Epoch 7/10
563/563 [==============================] - 129s 230ms/step - loss: 0.0160 - accuracy: 0.9949 - val_loss: 0.0536 - val_accuracy: 0.9946
Epoch 8/10
 81/563 [===>..........................] - ETA: 1:39 - loss: 0.0222 - accuracy: 0.9945
```

Training with distribution strategy

[Full console-dump on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/3ngBDXAT)

```
563/563 [==============================] - 119s 211ms/step - loss: 1.0535 - accuracy: 0.5099 - val_loss: 1.0735 - val_accuracy: 0.6682
Epoch 2/10
563/563 [==============================] - 95s 169ms/step - loss: 1.0123 - accuracy: 0.5277 - val_loss: 1.0721 - val_accuracy: 0.6682
Epoch 3/10
563/563 [==============================] - 95s 169ms/step - loss: 1.0121 - accuracy: 0.5277 - val_loss: 1.0709 - val_accuracy: 0.6682
Epoch 4/10
563/563 [==============================] - 95s 169ms/step - loss: 1.0124 - accuracy: 0.5277 - val_loss: 1.0667 - val_accuracy: 0.6682
Epoch 5/10
563/563 [==============================] - 95s 169ms/step - loss: 1.0121 - accuracy: 0.5277 - val_loss: 1.0687 - val_accuracy: 0.6682
Epoch 6/10
563/563 [==============================] - 95s 168ms/step - loss: 1.0125 - accuracy: 0.5277 - val_loss: 1.0638 - val_accuracy: 0.6682
Epoch 7/10
563/563 [==============================] - 94s 167ms/step - loss: 1.0125 - accuracy: 0.5277 - val_loss: 1.0639 - val_accuracy: 0.6682
Epoch 8/10
400/563 [====================>.........] - ETA: 24s - loss: 1.0135 - accuracy: 0.5268
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this error by increasing the max_queue_size argument in model.fit()

Comment: Could you please give a bit more information? When I look at the model.fit() arguments I see max_queue_size is related to keras generators but I don't see generators in your code.